# How to show profiler tab in Java VisualVM?

Tags: java, profiling, jvisualvm

I have launched a java application with the following arguments :

```
java
  -server
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=6789
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
  -Dvisualvm.display.name=MyApp
  -cp <classpath>
  ... application arguments ...
```

I can see my application in jvisualvm but the Profiler tab doesn't show up.

What arguments should I add to my application command line ?

**JDK 1.6.0_24-b07**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This did not help me, I got the desired Profiler tab to appear after running my application under jdk6.
The versions must agree, also check if one is 32-bit and the other 64-bit.

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same problem once and in my scenario the user running my java program and the user used for the jvisualvm were different. Check if you are also running into the same issue.Here is the snippet from JVisualVM documentation.

> The target application is running on the same host as Java VisualVM but was started by a different user than the one who started Java VisualVM. Java VisualVM discovers running applications using the jps tool, which can only discover Java applications started by  the same user as the one who starts the Java VisualVM tool.

Comment: This did not help me, I got the desired Profiler tab to appear after running my application under jdk6.

Comment: I am also facing similar problem. Is it because I am running VisualVM on my windows box but I want to profile tomcat application sitting in EC2?